# How upper sheet of hyperboloid can be covered by a single coordinate system?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

> How upper sheet of hyperboloid can be covered by a single coordinate system?

---

First let consider  $f(x,y,z)=z^2-x^2-y^2-a^2$. Now i visualize from here that if we consider any open ball ($x^2+y^2<a^2$) then visually it can be covered whole upper sheet of hyperboloid by magnifying it .But i can't find any map or any type co-ordinate chart ...
[image]

**Edited:** Now how can we prove that upper sheet of hyperboloid is a manifold  in the sense that every point on it has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$???(map is one-one but how prove it onto  ????)

Comment: For your added question: My explanation of the relation of $z$ to $x$ and $y$ can be reversed, so the map is also clearly "onto". In fact, for $x,y,z$ on the surface, the map $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y)$ is an inverse to the parameterization I wrote down, so the parameterization is 1-1 and onto its image.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that 
$$
f(x,y,z)=z^2-x^2-y^2-a^2
$$
is **not** the equation of the hyperboloid. Rather
$$
z^2-x^2-y^2-a^2 = 0
$$
is the equation. And for any point $(x, y, z)$ on the upper sheet, we'll have
\begin{align}
z^2 &= a^2 + x^2 + y^2 \\
z &> 0.
\end{align}
Taking the square root of the first equation gives
\begin{align}
z &= \pm \sqrt{a^2 + x^2 + y^2} \\
\end{align}
but applying the second yields 
\begin{align}
z &=  \sqrt{a^2 + x^2 + y^2}.
\end{align}

And now, because the set of $x,y,z$-triples satisfying that equation constitute a function-graph, it's easy. The paramaterization is
$$
(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, \sqrt{a^2 + x^2 + y^2}).
$$